# How to execute Linq to EF to search for string in a comma separated string field & replace the matched value in comma separeated with empty string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a class as below. I want to remove the Id value from the comma separated Colors if the endDate<currentdate using linq to EF in .net. So for the 2nd item, Id=2,replace remove 2 from Colors of that corresponding row

```cs
var mylist = new List<Product>{
    new Product{Id=1, Name="p-1",EndDate=DateTime.Parse("09-23-2022"), Colors="1,2"},
    new Product{Id=2, Name="p-2", EndDate=DateTime.Parse("08-02-2022"),Colors="2,1"},
    new Product{Id=3, Name="p-3",EndDate=DateTime.Parse("08-02-2022"), Colors="3,4,5"},
    new Product{Id=4, Name="p-4",EndDate=DateTime.Parse("09-23-2022"), Colors="4,5,3"}
};

var filteredLines = mylist.
    Where(x => x.EndDate < DateTime.Now).Select(l => 
        l.Colors.Replace(l.Colors, l.Colors(x=>x.Colors.NotContain("id")))
    );
```

I want to remove Id value from Colors wherever the enddate<datetime.now

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this. The first two Linq Arguments are used to determine what elements must be changed. Then in the last one we create an Array from your colors, find the index of the one with the ID and remove it afterwards. The index is -1 when the element was not found. In the end we return the Product with the changed colors list.

```
myList.Where(x => x.EndDate < DateTime.Now)
      .Where(x => x.Id != null)
      .Select(x => {
         var colors = x.Colors.Split(",");
         var index = colors.IndexOf(x.Id);
         if(index != -1)
            colors.RemoveAt(index);
         return product with {
             Colors = string.Join(",", colors)
         } 
      });
```

It would be easier for you, if you save the colors directly as a list.

Note:
I assumed that Product is a record. If not you can use the same code but with a ForEach instead of the select.

```
myList.Where(x => x.EndDate < DateTime.Now)
          .Where(x => x.Id != null)
          .ForEach(x => {
             var colors = x.Colors.Split(",");
             var index = colors.IndexOf(x.Id);
             if(index != -1)
                colors.RemoveAt(index);
             x.Colors = colors;
          });
```